# image resize and crop on upload asp,net

Tags: asp.net, image, resize, crop

i have the below code, i am looking to crop and resize at the same time, i use the below function, i am looking to have 150 x 150 px image size cropped centered, but the below function always if the image width > height, the output image will be 200x150, but i need it to be 150x150 px,, any help

```
Function SavetoDisk(FU As FileUpload, ByVal para_Save_to_Path As String, ByVal maxHeight As Integer, ByVal maxWidth As Integer, para_FileExt As String, anchor As AnchorPosition)

    Using image As Image = image.FromStream(FU.PostedFile.InputStream)

        Dim sourceWidth As Integer = image.Width

        Dim sourceHeight As Integer = image.Height
        Dim sourceX As Integer = 0
        Dim sourceY As Integer = 0
        Dim destX As Integer = 0
        Dim destY As Integer = 0

        Dim nPercent As Decimal = 0
        Dim nPercentW As Decimal = 0
        Dim nPercentH As Decimal = 0

        nPercentW = (Convert.ToSingle(maxWidth) / Convert.ToSingle(sourceWidth))
        nPercentH = (Convert.ToSingle(maxHeight) / Convert.ToSingle(sourceHeight))

        If (nPercentH < nPercentW) Then
            nPercent = nPercentW
            Select Case (anchor)
                Case AnchorPosition.Top
                    destY = 0
                Case AnchorPosition.Bottom
                    destY = Convert.ToInt32(maxHeight - (sourceHeight * nPercent))
                Case Else
                    destY = Convert.ToInt32((maxHeight - (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2)
            End Select
        Else
            nPercent = nPercentH
            Select Case (anchor)
                Case AnchorPosition.Left
                    destX = 0
                Case AnchorPosition.Right
                    destX = Convert.ToInt32((maxWidth - (sourceWidth * nPercent)))
                Case Else
                    destX = Convert.ToInt32(((maxWidth - (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2))
            End Select
        End If

        Dim destWidth As Integer = Convert.ToInt32((sourceWidth * nPercent))
        Dim destHeight As Integer = Convert.ToInt32((sourceHeight * nPercent))

        Using thumbnailBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight)

            Using thumbnailGraph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailBitmap)

                thumbnailGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
                thumbnailGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
                thumbnailGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
                Dim imageRectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, destHeight, destHeight)
                thumbnailGraph.DrawImage(image, New Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight), New Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

                Dim jpegCodec As ImageCodecInfo = Findcodecinfo("JPEG")
                If Not IsNothing(jpegCodec) Then
                    Dim encoderParameters As EncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(1)
                    encoderParameters.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 80)
                    thumbnailBitmap.Save(para_Save_to_Path, jpegCodec, encoderParameters)
                Else
                    thumbnailBitmap.Save(para_Save_to_Path, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                End If
            End Using

        End Using

    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: Take a look at ImageResizer API?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to achieve what you want:

1. Figure out ratio of height to width
2. Scale the larger dimension down to 150px and the smaller dimension down to ratio * 150px.
3. Draw the result in the middle of a 150x150 bitmap.

This code will do exactly that (c#):

```
using ( Image img = Image.FromStream( FU.PostedFile.InputStream ) )
{
    int sourceWidth = img.Width;
    int sourceHeight = img.Height;

    int desiredHeight = 150;
    int desiredWidth = 150;

    double heightToWidthRatio = sourceHeight / ( double )sourceWidth;

    //This draw method will always center the image horizonally or vertically, as appropriate
    using ( Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = new Bitmap( desiredWidth, desiredHeight ) )
    {
        using ( Graphics thumbnailGraph = Graphics.FromImage( thumbnailBitmap ) )
        {
            thumbnailGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            thumbnailGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            thumbnailGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            float destWidth = ( heightToWidthRatio > 1f ) ? ( float )( desiredWidth / heightToWidthRatio ) : desiredWidth;
            float destHeight = ( heightToWidthRatio > 1f ) ? desiredHeight : ( float )( desiredHeight * heightToWidthRatio );
            float destX = ( desiredWidth - destWidth ) / 2f;
            float destY = ( desiredHeight - destHeight ) / 2f;

            thumbnailGraph.DrawImage( img, new RectangleF( destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight ),
                                              new Rectangle( sourceWidth, sourceHeight, sourceWidth, sourceHeight ),
                                              GraphicsUnit.Pixel );
        }

    }
}
```

Continue to write out the file as you have been, previously.
The important part is the four float values in the middle and the fact that it uses a RectangleF in the DrawImage function, to truly center, even on fractional values.
If you do not want that behavior due to excessive antialiasing, just Math.Floor the values and continue to use Rectangle and ints.

Comment: lets say that the dimensions of the original picture is 400 x 600, the function above will  crop it center and resize it to be exactly 150 x 150 or what?